# Probability of two consecutive events happening in a sequence

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

I have a kind of specific problem for which I would need a general solution, but I can't figure it out so far and I also don't really know what to google for to find some hints. So I would appreciate any help on this.

Consider a sequence of binary random events $A_1, A_2, ..., A_n$, where the events are independent, not mutually exclusive and **not** equally distributed ($P(A_i)$ is usually not equal to $P(A_j)$, where $j\neq i$; we could define for easier writing: $p_i := P(A_i)$).
Now I want to know for any $n$, what is the probability that any two consecutive events $A_i,A_{i-1}$ with $1<i\leq n$ are fulfilled?
Actually I would like to have a general solution not only for two consecutive events, but for any number $N$ of consecutive events. But for now I only consider the most simple case $N=2$, which I can't even solve already.

What I tried was to define composite events $B_i$, where $B_i := A_i \wedge A_{i-1}$ (note that I use logical notation $\wedge$ instead of the usual $\cap$, because I'm dealing with binary events and this way it feels more natural to me, but it's actually the same thing).
But now consecutive events $B_i$ are dependent on each other, because they share a common event $A$.

Now I try to solve the equation for the probability, that at least one event $B$ occurs until trial $n$. Or the other way around: The probability that none of the events $B$ occur until trial $n$. So I try to find:
$$p_{B,n} = P(B_2 \vee B_3 \vee ... \vee B_n)$$
or:
$$q_{B,n} = P(\lnot B_2 \wedge \lnot B_3 \wedge ... \wedge \lnot B_n)$$
And to find a general solution for this appears to be ... maybe not impossible, but I can't figure it out. I'm really "computing myself to death" with this. I tried to break down the above (logical) equation to events $A$ and tried to find a pattern, but this is getting extremely ugly and I can't find a general form.
But I wonder: Shouldn't there already exist a solution for something like this? At least I can't find it :(

I also tried to use the chain-rule (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_(probability)), but that doesn't seem to help much.

Edit: Something important I forgot to mention:
The general solution I'm looking for is supposed to be an iterative way of computing $p_{B,n}$ (or $q_{B,n}$), because I get the sequence of probabilities $p_i = P(A_i)$ frame-wise in a simulation and I like to compute $p_{B,i}$ for every frame $i$. So I'm basically looking for a function $f$, such that:
$$p_{B,i} = f(p_i, p_{B,i-1})$$
(if such a thing exists)